# Amazon Photos iOS app, can it delete photos and videos from the phone after backing them up?

Tags: video, iphone, photos, ios

I would like the Amazon Photos app to automatically delete the photos and video it has backed up. Is there a simple way to do this?

Is there any solution for deleting all photos and videos from iOS without:

1. Deleting settings
2. Connecting to a macOS machine to use Image Capture
3. selecting all the photos by hand.

Comment: I also want this. Did you find a way?